# Fetching the loss values (MAE) per iteration using sklearn MLPRegressor

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I want to check my loss values using MSE during the training process, how to fetching the loss values using MSE at each of iteration?., thank you.

```
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor 
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error

dataset = open_dataset("forex.csv")

dataset_vector = [float(i[-1]) for i in dataset]
normalized_dataset_vector = normalize_vector(dataset_vector)
training_vector, validation_vector, testing_vector = split_dataset(training_size, validation_size, testing_size, normalized_dataset_vector)
training_features = get_features(training_vector)
training_fact = get_fact(training_vector)
validation_features = get_features(validation_vector)
validation_fact = get_fact(validation_vector)
model = MLPRegressor(activation=activation, alpha=alpha, hidden_layer_sizes=(neural_net_structure[1],), max_iter=number_of_iteration, random_state=seed)
model.fit(training_features, training_fact)
pred = model.predict(training_features)
err = mean_absolute_error(pred, validation_fact)
print(err)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no callbacks object like there is in `Keras` so you'll have to loop over the fitting process to get it for each iteration. Something like the below will work for you

```
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error

# create some toy data
X = np.random.random((100, 5))
y = np.random.choice([0, 1], 100)

max_iter = 500

mlp = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(10, 10, 10), max_iter=max_iter)

errors = []
for i in range(max_iter):
    mlp.partial_fit(X, y, classes=[0, 1])
    pred = mlp.predict(X)
    errors.append(mean_absolute_error(y, pred))
```

Which throws an annoying `DeprecationWarning` at the moment, but that can be ignored. The only problem with using this method is that you have to manually keep track of whether or not your model has converged. Personally I would suggest using `Keras` instead of `sklearn` if you want to work with neural networks.

Comment: Thank you for help, this is my project to compare 2 algorithm, I have completed another algorithm using sklearn method, so i should using sklearn for testing